# iOS 8 beta / xcode 6 volatile absolute path

Tags: ios, xcode

I've observed some strange behaviour when testing an application on Xcode 6 with iOS 8 beta devices.

I am using the application's absolute bundle path as part of a salt, and I've noticed that each `build & run` in Xcode results in a modified absolute bundle path.  The bundle path remains the same, however, when I `run without building` or launch the application from the device.

It remains to be seen whether this behaviour will persist following the official iOS 8 release, but I haven't tracked down any documentation or discussion of this increased iOS 8 bundle path volatility.

Perhaps this is another subtle *don't rely on the bundle path for anything* recommendation from Apple?  Does anybody have any other insight into why this may have changed?

Comment: The path to an app can change. You must NEVER rely on the app's absolute path.

Comment: Under what conditions does it change?  Is there no documentation around this?  I've observed that it only changes upon app installation.

Comment: The path will change if you post an update to your app and then a user installs the update. The update gets installed into a new path.

Comment: Having run a large number of upgrade tests I know that is not correct in the general case.  It could be true for an iTunes App Store upgrade (which I have not had the liberty of testing as often), but I know that upgrades via ad hoc distribution bundle do not change the path.  FWIW, I am aware of the rhetoric around avoiding absolute path usage, but the approach for the time being is tried and tested.

Comment: Yes, it is true that the absolute path changes when the user installs an update from the app store.  We didn't see it in our development builds with upgrades, but perhaps Apple is trying to make dev build upgrades behave like app store upgrades to prevent developers from using absolute path.  We had an issue with our app because of storing absolute paths, and broke functionality when we pushed a new version.  Having it break during development would have been preferable.

Comment: I found out during debugging today that if the there's a crash in the app on the device, its bundle path changes than what it used to be previously. I was storing its path in a NSUserDefault, but when the app crashed, it was different than what it used to be.